# Aligning flex items horizontally in a vertical flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, html

I can't figure out for the life of me how to make this page work.

I'm trying to have the "Top" be a header, the "Bottom" be the footer, and "table" and "section" be two separate columns in between.

Although I can't figure it out. Thanks.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}
#pageTop {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#table {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  flex-grow: 8;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
#pageSection {
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 50%;
  flex-flow: 8;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
#pageBot {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="pageTop">Top</div>
  <nav id="table">table</nav>
  <div id="pageSection">section</div>
  <div id="pagebot">Bottom</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wrap the table and the section in one container. That container becomes the second flex item in the parent flex container. The add `display: flex` to the new container.

Comment: Do you want #table and #pageSection to be above and below eachother or side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a div with flex row, as it (adjust cols width with `width` attribute):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}
#pageTop {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: .5em;
}
#mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#table {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;

}
#pageSection {
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 50%;

}
#pagebot {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="pageTop">Top</div>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <nav id="table">table</nav>
    <div id="pageSection">section</div>
  </div>
  <div id="pagebot">Bottom</div>
</body>
```

PS: I also fixed a pagebot/pageBot variant. Be aware, CSS is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Like Micheal_B stated:

> Wrap the `#table` and the `#section` in one container. That container becomes the second flex item in the parent flex container. Then add `display: flex` to the new container.

#### Changes

- Added `main#pageContent` to body and wrapped it around `nav#table` and `section#pageSection`

  - Added `display: flex`, `justify-content: center`, and `flex: 2 0 auto`
- Changed all `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to `flex` shorthand.

  - ex. `flex: 0 1 auto` = `flex-grow: 0` `flex-shrink: 1` `flex-basis: auto`
  - note. The ruleset above is default for all flex children.
- Removed `align-content` and `justify-content`; and changed the value of `flex-wrap` from `wrap` to `nowrap`; and added `overflow:hidden` and `width: 100%` to normalize a little.
- Added `width: 100%` to everything with the exception of `#pageSection` and `#table`.
- Added `height: 2em` to `#pageTop` and `#pageBot`(BTW, corrected typo)
- Changed all of the tags to it's semantic equivalents.

#### `main#pageContent`

- Height is set up to take up the freespace that the footer and header leave by `height: calc(100% - 4em)`. This probably overkill since it also has `flex: 2 0 auto`.
- It is a flex container (`flex: display`) and a flex child (`flex: 2 0 auto`)

#### `section#pageSection`

- `overflow-x: hidden` will prevent any content from busting out of the borders sideways. `overflow-y:auto` will accommodate any content that extends the bottom border by adding a scrollbar. I have added content (a few `<p>`) to demonstrate.

#### SNIPPET

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#pageContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 4em);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 2 0 auto;
}
#pageTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: violet;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#table {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#pageSection {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#pageBot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="pageTop">Top</header>
  <main id='pageContent'>
    <nav id="table">table</nav>
    <section id="pageSection">
      <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.</p>

      <p>He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>

      <p>His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream.</p>

      <p>His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls.</p>

      <p>A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted
        out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops</p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer id="pageBot">Bottom</footer>
</body>
```